# Checking if a a file exists vs. directory in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

Is there a difference between checking if a file exists or a directory?

For example, if we had a command in UNIX which checked if:
"C:/HelloWorld/hello.java" exists
vs.
"C:/HelloWorld" exists

when those exact values are fed in, would it differentiate between a file or a directory? or are files also considered to be a form of directory path?

Comment: `C:/HelloWorld` and `C:/HelloWorld/hello.java` probably do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether "something exists" or whether a file exists or whether a directory exists (or a few others, see `man test`)

```
if [ -e "/path/to/something" ]; then
   printf "Something exists there\n"
fi
if [ -f "/path/to/something" ]; then
    printf "There is a file there\n"
fi
if [ -d "/path/to/something" ]; then
    printf "There is a directory there\n"
fi
```

but you have to test each part, if `C:/HelloWorld` does not exist then neither will `c:/HelloWorld/hello.java`, but you wouldn't know if the directory exists if you just know that file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks.
Just to reconfirm, so by using the -e flag, it wouldn't make a difference whether the path fed to it is a file or a directory? It is possible to just confirm 'something' exists regardless?

Comment: @Kyanite : Yes `-e` will do as you require. As a  programmer, you need to learn to make small tests to prove to yourself the truth or false(ness) of a hypothesis. Executing the above code would be very easy for you to test as many scenarios as you can imagine to "confirm 'something' exists". Yes? Go and prosper! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is this, the code to check if file or directory exists, is this.

Behind the scenes, the library makes a call to the filesystem manager via well-known API, to check for the inode that matches up to the parameter (either file or directory).

Then the API can determine based on the filesystem attributes if it has the inode allocated which indicates the file or directory exists.